# Create array of values from a nested object using _Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've been having a heck of a time trying to figure this out. Still relatively new to _Underscore JS and I'm attempting to create an array of unique values from an array of nested objects. Example data below:

```
[  
   {  
      "property":"prop1",
      "list":[  
         {  
            "description":"description blah",
            "type":"F",
            "values":{  
               "value1":30.0,
               "value2":0.0
            }
         },
         {  
            "description":"description blah",
            "type":"F",
            "values":{  
               "value1":30.0,
               "value2":0.0
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "property":"prop2",
      "list":[  
         {  
            "description":"description blah",
            "type":"Q",
            "values":{  
               "value1":30.0,
               "value2":0.0
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What I'm attempting to get back is an array of ALL the UNIQUE nested "type" values. Example of data back below:

```
["F","Q"]
```

I've attempted `_.pluck` and `_.map` with little success. Would I need to utilize something different, such as chaining them? Appreciate any help I could get on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses chaining:

```
let result = _.chain(data)
    .pluck('list')
    .flatten()
    .pluck('type')
    .uniq()
    .value();
```

This works by first [**plucking**](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) the lists from the data and [**flattening**](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) them. Then the type is plcuked from the list before finally calling [**uniq**](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) to get the unique types.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect!

Comment: Awesome answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this regular JS and `reduce` (sorry, I'm not very familiar with underscore, so I figured I'd offer a vanilla solution for now)

```
var uniqueValues = data.reduce(function(vals, d) {
    return vals.concat(d.list.reduce(function(listVals, l) {
        if (vals.indexOf(l.type) === -1 && listVals.indexOf(l.type) === -1) {
            listVals.push(l.type)
        }

        return listVals;
    }, []))
}, [])
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0dsdm7Lu/

Answer (score 0):

```
_.unique(_.flatten(_.map(myList, item => _.map(item.list, i => i.type))));
```

Underscore is not the greatest when it comes to composing functions since it takes data first.  `lodash-fp` and `ramda` are much better in this regard.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8eLk7t15/

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't my choice. If it were my choice, I would've chose lodash (ultimately because I've heard it tends to be superior in many ways). So I currently do have to stick with underscore. I like the clean look to lodash though, thanks anyways :(

Comment: It's actually underscore.

Comment: I apologize, I thought you were suggesting lodash, and supplying lodash code. Should've looked closer at your jsfiddle. Although I do still prefer the chaining method utilized by accepted answer. Thanks bud!